# In Powershell, how do I input <datetime>?

Tags: powershell

For example, if I am trying to retrieve eventlog before a specific date and time.

```
Get-EventLog system -Before (what do I enter here?)
```

Essentially, what on earth is the format for entering datetimes?

Comment: Please try google before asking.  "Powershell datetime". First result: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730960.aspx

Comment: `help Get-EventLog -full`

Comment: I wasn't putting the date in quotations is the reason. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
Get-EventLog System -Before "2/22/2017 7:00am"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.management/Get-EventLog

-Before requires a type of DateTime

You need to use that. Simple as that.

There are many ways to satisfy this in powershell. Here is one example which can be used for the -Before parameter and another for the -After which takes the same type

```
$dt = Get-Date

Get-EventLog system -Before $dt -after "2/15/2017 8:27:50 PM" -LogName System
```